# Error: The client token cannot be used for this API

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth, facebook-timeline

I am trying to publish Facebook Timeline actions using the app access token instead of the user's access token (so that I don't have to deal with expiring sessions), as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

This was working fine, but stopped working a few days ago, now giving me this error:

> The client token cannot be used for this API

Any ideas on why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Resetting our app secret and then getting a new app token seems to fix it, but I'd still love to know what happened.