# Facebook Error: "The client token cannot be used for this API" - works on DEV and STAGE but not on LIVE app?

Tags: facebook, token

I've built a notification sending system that sends notifications to all users of our app, using the app access token.  This system is currently running on my localhost.  When I configure it with the appid and appsecret for my dev and stage environments, it works fine.  But when I put in the appid and appsecret of the LIVE app, I get this error:

{"message":"The client token cannot be used for this API", "type":"OAuthException", "code":190}

So what's different between dev and live?  Dev and Stage are in sandbox mode, Live is not.  So I tried disabling sandbox mode on Dev/Stage and they continue to function fine.  Dev works fine, Stage works fine, Live gives this error.  All other code is the same except for the appid, appsecret, and redirect_uri (changing it to match the domain of each environment).

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188571/error-the-client-token-cannot-be-used-for-this-api) post, but unfortunately resetting our appsecret on a site with 1,000,000 users is not something we can do at the moment (too much other functionality relies on it).

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the client token, not the app secret - the error message means that at some point your app was set to 'desktop / native' (as opposed to 'web') under 'App Type' -

Previously this meant that your app access token was embedded in your client code and thus not to be trusted for making app-signed requests.

If your client token is identical to the app secret (which it will be if you've never changed it) Facebook still considers it to be unsafe to trust; you'll need to change the client token, which is under Advanced settings, Security:

[image]